# In android, How can I get the correct value of frequency in real time?

Tags: android, audio, fft, frequency

I have looked at every single answer here and I do not understand them... I am able to obtain the graph but how can I just have a single value for the current frequency... I'd appreciate code answers rather than mathematical ones..

```
 public class RecordAudio extends AsyncTask<Void, double[], Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        try {
            // int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(frequency,
            // AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
            int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(frequency,
                    channelConfiguration, audioEncoding);

            AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord(
                    MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, frequency,
                    channelConfiguration, audioEncoding, bufferSize);

            //  double[] audioDataDoubles = new double[(blockSize*2)]; // Same values as above, as doubles
            //   -----------------------------------------------
            double[] re = new double[blockSize];
            double[] im = new double[blockSize];
            double[] magnitude = new double[blockSize];
            int sampleRate = 8000;                             // Sample rate in Hz

            short[] buffer = new short[blockSize];
            double[] toTransform = new double[blockSize];

            audioRecord.startRecording();

            // started = true; hopes this should true before calling
            // following while loop

            while (started) {
                int bufferReadResult = audioRecord.read(buffer, 0,
                        blockSize);

                 for (int i = 0; i < blockSize && i < bufferReadResult; i++) {
                    toTransform[i] = (double) buffer[i] / 32768.0; // signed
                    // 16
                }                                       // bit
                transformer.ft(toTransform);



                publishProgress(toTransform);



            }

            audioRecord.stop();

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("AudioRecord", "Recording Failed");
        }
        return null;
    }
    public   double Index2Freq(int i, double samples, int nFFT) {
        return (double) i * (samples / nFFT / 2.);
    }
    public   int calculateF(int sampleRate, double [] audioData){

        int numSamples = audioData.length;
        int numCrossing = 0;
        for (int p = 0; p < numSamples-1; p++)
        {
            if ((audioData[p] > 0 && audioData[p + 1] <= 0) ||
                    (audioData[p] < 0 && audioData[p + 1] >= 0))
            {
                numCrossing++;
            }
        }

        float numSecondsRecorded = (float)numSamples/(float)sampleRate;
        float numCycles = numCrossing/2;
        float frequency = numCycles/numSecondsRecorded;

        return (int)frequency;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(double[]... toTransform) {

        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

        for (int i = 0; i < toTransform[0].length; i++) {
            int x = i;
            int downy = (int) (100 - (toTransform[0][i] * 10));
            int upy = 100;



            canvas.drawLine(x, downy, x, upy, paint);
        }

        imageView.invalidate();

           TxtV.setText("Frequency = "+String.valueOf(calculateF(8000, toTransform[0])));

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

}
```

Comment: Probably you did not like the answers you found, because the reality is not simple.  What is to say that there is only a single frequency present?  And your frequency resolution of the components you do find is limited by the number of samples you calculate the Fourier transform over (though you can cheat to a limited degree by zero padding).

Comment: I'm basically looking for the code that gets the properly calculated frequency based on toTransform[0] elements

Comment: Look for the strongest one, convert the bin number back to frequency.  Run test cases with known input if you find it confusing.

Comment: how can i convert the bin number back to frequency

Comment: Run some experiments with known inputs and you will understand that far more thoroughly than having someone hand you the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by current frequency, you mean something about captured audio, realize that live sound is composed of a massive number of frequencies, so you will never get just one frequency result.

This is true even for a single musical pitch (except maybe for synthesized pure sinusoidal test data in zero noise).

Comment: Then I want to do the same thing that most other apps do... they somehow give a frequency that is highly accurate!